# Rails: Only see user's own information in admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I am creating an admin-panel for a website where my 15 user/companies can login, alter their information, add products etc. They are not admins.

I have a User-table with attributes such as (slightly simplified):

```
email:string, password:string, company_id:integer, is_admin:boolean
```

Additionally, I have a number of other tables such as Products, Reviews etc which contain the attribute company_id and '`:belongs_to company`' in their Models.

In addition to the 15 company users I have my own admin user account, which is the only one set to `is_admin = true`. No company_id is set for this user account.

In the admin panel I have Products and Reviews-tabs which shows a number of products and reviews.

**My question / problem**

What I would like to do is quite straightforward and I expect an elegant solution to this, since it seems to be quite a normal problem.

- I want the admin to see ALL products and ALL reviews in the Products and Reviews-tab.
- I want the normal company user (is_admin = false) to only see and alter their own Products and Reviews, i.e. filtered according to the company_id attribute.

My solution so far is to have something like this (@current_user is the logged in user):

```
# index
if is_admin
@products = Product.all
else
@products = Product.where(:company_id => @current_user.company_id)
end
```

...and something similar for #show and so on. This works but it feels like there must be a more elegant way of handling this? In fact, I have some 10-12 Models such as Product and Reviews, and there might be more.

What is the best way of handling this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your original solution works, my original answer might not be very helpful. Perhaps you can just define your model objects in your user show controller?

```
def show
   if @current_user.is_admin
    @products = Product.all
    @reviews = Review.all
  else
    @products = @current_user.products
    @reviews = @current_user.products
  end
```

And then include a <% @products.each do |product| %> in each tab, etc.

(Most of my original answer, which is more complicated and similar to what you were doing:)

```
def index
  if @current_user.is_admin
    @products = Product.all
  else
    @products = @current_user.products
  end
end
```

And in each index.html.erb file:

```
<h2>Product List</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Title</td>
  <td>Description</td>
</tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= product.title %></td>
  <td><%= product.description %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much exactly what I do and it sure does work but I need to handle it for every index/show etc. and I have some 10-12 controllers similar to Product / Review...maybe this IS the only solution. I was hoping for some smart before_filter or something that would do some magic. My gut feeling is that there should be something more elegant than this...

Comment: Maybe you can keep everything in the admin panel (user/admin show page) and forego the index pages, to keep it all in one place? Perhaps someone else might know of a more elegant solution.

Comment: Perhaps someone else might know of a more elegant solution, where you can iterate through all the has_many classes your User has without explicitly defining each one, this would be in the view though (ex. for user.children.each do |child|, Child.each do |child_instance|, child_instance.title).

Comment: Well, I guess there might at least not be a standard, well-known way of handling this that "everyone" knows of (but me). I think I might have to go with this version of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a simple role authorization scheme.
admin_controller.rb would be a good place for this.  Using a before_filter, see if the user is an administrator.  If so that user would have additional access.

Comment: I believe a before_filter would be the place to solve this but how to actually solve it is another question. The is_admin is only one part of the problem, the other is to filter each controller with company_id.